# Setting up SVN in Xcode 4 problem

Tags: xcode, macos, svn

I am trying to set up SVN Repo in Xcode 4. This is my first time doing this. After I enter my info and there a green light saying host is reachable, I am brought up to this screen and the activity monitor just keeps spinning and nothing happen. What am i doing wrong?
I am in the "Root" section, and watch youtube video showing how to do this, after setting up the repo, when the go to the "Root" section, a pop up automatically pops up asking for their user/pass, it doesn't happen to me. 
Thanks
[image]

**Update:** I restart Xcode and it asked for my password and I successfully logged in. The only problem now is, it stays, "Unable to load revisions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVN support in Xcode 4 is hopelessly broken.  It works on occasion - but other times it is totally non-functional.  Git support works quite a bit better.  I don't use the SVN support for this reason.

Comment: Yea, I fixed it but it's very glitchy. Had to do several hacks to get it work. thanks for your reply.